# Python convertion of list of strings to list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

How to convert following list

```
['abc,cde,eg,ba', 'abc,cde,ba']
```

in to list of tuples?

```
[('abc','cde','eg','ba'), ('abc','cde','ba')]
```

What I have tried

```
output = []

for item in my_list:
    a = "','".join((item.split(',')))
    output.append(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you are splitting the string (which will give you a list), but then you are joining it back with a `,`, which is returning to you the same string:

```
 >>> 'a,b'.split(',')
 ['a', 'b']
 >>> ','.join('a,b'.split(','))
'a,b'
```

You can convert a list to a tuple by passing it to the the built-in `tuple()` method.

Combining the above with a list comprehension (which is an expression that evaluates to a list), gives you what you need:

```
>>> [tuple(i.split(',')) for i in ['abc,cde,eg,ba', 'abc,cde,ba']]
[('abc', 'cde', 'eg', 'ba'), ('abc', 'cde', 'ba')]
```

The longhand way of writing that is:

```
result = []
for i in ['abc,cde,eg,ba', 'abc,cde,ba']:
    result.append(tuple(i.split(',')))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t=['abc,cde,eg,ba', 'abc,cde,ba']

for i in t:
    print tuple(i.split(','))
```

Comment: nataraj サンダーナタラジ : Thanks, performs well :)

Answer (score 1):

you can split the 2 elements. Here is my code

```
['abc,cde,eg,ba', 'abc,cde,ba']
a='abc,cde,eg,ba'
b='abc,cde,ba'
c=[]
c.append(tuple(a.split(',')))
c.append(tuple(b.split(',')))
print c
```