# Python function is creating an extra tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, tuples, python-itertools

I based my original function on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938276/how-to-convert-nested-list-of-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples-in-python-3-3?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529086/python-convert-a-list-of-list-to-list-of-tuples), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852462/python-convertion-of-list-of-strings-to-list-of-tuples). But it's not working. The main gotcha I'm getting is that even when I put tuple(c) in Example Two, I still get a list back.

I have two examples, one with nested tuples (the way it should be) and one with nested tuples in a list so that you can easily see the extra enclosure since there are too many parenthesis with nested tuples.

```
def example_one():
    list_one = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
    list_two = []
    print "List One: " + str(list_one)      
    for i in range(0, 5):
        c_tuple = tuple(c for c in itertools.combinations(list_one[:i], i))
        list_two.append(c_tuple)
    list_two = tuple(list_two)
    print "List Two: " + str(list_two)
```

Outputs:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: (((),), (((1, 2),),), (((1, 2), (3, 4)),), (((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)),), (((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)),))
```

and

```
def example_two():
    list_one = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
    list_two = []
    print "List One: " + str(list_one)      
    for i in range(0, 5):
       c_tuple = [tuple(c) for c in itertools.combinations(list_one[:i], i)]
       list_two.append(c_tuple)
    list_two = tuple(list_two)
    print "List Two: " + str(list_two)
```

Outputs:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: ([()], [((1, 2),)], [((1, 2), (3, 4))], [((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))], [((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))])
```

In the second example, the parenthesis represent the tuple in example one that I am trying to eliminate. In fact, to be honest, I am not sure if it is that tuple or the one inside that. Whichever one is being added unnecessarily I guess.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: ((()), ((1, 2)), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you have mentioned, you could avoid doing `[tuple(c) for c in iterable]` and just do the following. (Also simplified / minified a lot of things)

```
>>> list_one = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
>>> list_two = []
>>> print "List One: ", list_one
List One:  ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
>>> list_two = tuple(
...     c for i in range(0, 5)
...     for c in itertools.combinations(list_one[:i], i)
... )
>>> print "List Two: ", list_two
List Two:  ((), ((1, 2),), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

Comment: No, its not the empty tuple at the beginning I am trying to get rid of: that is supposed to be there. I am trying to get rid of the extra tuple wrapping the second wrapped tuple. For example: (()), ((1, 2)), ((2, 3), (3, 4))... is good. I am getting: ((())), (((1, 2))), (((2, 3), (3, 4)))...

Comment: I believe the problem would have originally been avoided if [tuple(c) for c in iterable] returned tuple(c) instead of list(c). Or else I am reading the output wrong.

Comment: Yes, updating my answer.

Comment: Placed desired output in question post. It was unclear.

Comment: In your example output, the second element (1, 2) still has 3 sets of parenthesis around it. So does the first. Should only be two sets. But I like your other refactor.

Comment: Oh okay, updated my answer. You need to note that nested comprehensions follow the order of the `for` loops as going deeper when you go left to right.

Comment: Yes, I think this one works. I need to work with it a little more to make sure, but can you explain what you did? I don't know if I'd have thought of it, and I don't think this is a trivial case.

Comment: I rearranged the list comprehension to the desired output. I followed what a normal loop would have looked like & transformed it to a comprehension. You can do the reverse to get a hint, but I'd suggest attempting it yourself first :)

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you are adding nested tuples in to a list, appending those lists into a big list and finally converting that big list to a tuple.
That's why you are getting the lists in your tuple

The line which is creating a lists is

`c_tuple = [tuple(c) for c in itertools.combinations(list_one[:i], i)]`

if you have the square braces, it will return a list only

Comment: remove the square braces

Answer (score 0):

You have to use extend instead of append while adding c_tuple to list_two!

To get a clear picture on the difference between two, Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend)

```
import itertools

def example_two():
    list_one = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
    list_two = []
    print "List One: " + str(list_one)      
    for i in range(0, 5):
       c_tuple = [tuple(c) for c in itertools.combinations(list_one[:i], i)]
       list_two.extend(c_tuple) #here instead of append use extend!
    list_two = tuple(list_two)
    print "List Two: " + str(list_two)
```

Output:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: ((), ((1, 2),), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

Hope it helps!